# Rational equation, A+B inseparable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\frac{5}{x^2+6x+8} = \frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{x+4}$

How to solve for $A+B$? I tried multiplying by common denominator and eliminating denominator on both side of equation. But then I get

$5=A(x+4)+B(x+2)$

From these point, how to separate the $A+B$ from factors $(x+4)$ and $(x+2)$

Comment: How about finding $A$, then finding $B$, then adding $A$ and $B$?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are constants, so they hold for any values of $x$. Setting $x=-4$ and $x=-2$ seems like a particularly convenient choice.

Comment: @TheCount And we know A and B are constants because they are not functions in x?

Comment: Yep! That's exactly it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from where you left off,

$$ 
5=A(x+4)+B(x+2) \\
5=Ax+4A+Bx+2B \\
0x+5=x(A+B)+4A+2B 
$$

We see that we need to satsify:

$$
A+B=0 \\
4A+2B=5
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, in fact, I don't even need to go on, b/c the problem asks for A+B and you solve for it directly

Answer (score 1):

I obtain
$$
5= x(A+B)+ 4A + 2B
$$
so that  $B=-A$ and $A=5/2$.

Answer (score 1):

No need to solve a system of equations.  Multiply
$$\frac{5}{(x+2)(x+4)}=\frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{x+4}$$
by $(x+2)$ to get
$$\frac{5}{x+4}=A+\frac{B(x+2)}{x+4},$$
then plug in $x=-2$ to obtain $5/2=A$.   Similarly after multiplying by $(x+4)$ and then plugging in $x=-4$ you'll get $5/(-2)=B$.